# Unreal Engine c++ GameplayCamerasSubsystem fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

The plugin GameplayCamera works well in blueprint,
but when I try to work with it in c++, I still have a problem resolving dependencies

Simple exemple:

```
MyCamereManager.cpp

#include "GameplayCamerasSubsystem.h"
```

here I try to get my subsystem:

```
UGameplayCamerasSubsystem* CamSubInstance = GetWorld()->GetSubsystem<UGameplayCamerasSubsystem>();
```

in my Build.cs
I add

```
"GameplayCameras",
```

Everything seems to work in VS, But when I try to build I get this error:

```
 error LNK2019: external symbol not resolved "private: static class UClass * __cdecl UGameplayCamerasSubsystem::GetPrivateStaticClass(void)" (?GetPrivateStaticClass@UGameplayCamerasSubsystem@@CAPEAVUClass@@XZ)
```

has anyone had a problem with this subsystem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: After including modules even `UGameplayCamerasSubsystem::GetGameplayCamerasSubsystem(GetWorld())`gives the same error as well. I wonder...